# Stratonovich Integral and Ito's lemma

Tags: stochastic-calculus

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},\mathbb{P},\{\mathcal{F}\}_t)$ be a filtered- probability space and $W_t$ be standard Wiener process. I want to show stratonovich integral of $W_t$, i.e $\int_{0}^{t} W_s ○ dW_s$ , is not a martingale by Ito lemma.

Thanks.

Comment: There is a conversion formula from stratonovich integral to ito integral: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stratonovich_integral.

Comment: After you have it converted, you can then use ito's lemma.

Comment: How, I can't prove this formula. I cant see prove of these in this page

Comment: You can not use Ito's lemma directly

Comment: Why? We can use Ito lema

Comment: Definition of Stratonovich Integral $\ne$ Definition of Ito Integral

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is well-known, $W_t$ is a continues, adapted and locally bounded process.Let $I=\{t_i\}_{i=0}^{n}$ is a sequence of partitions of $[0,t]$, Indeed $0=t_0<t_1<\cdots<t_n=t$ .By definition of stratonovich integral, we have 
$$\int_{0}^{t} W_s\circ dW_s=\frac{1}{2}\underset{n\to \infty }{\mathop{\lim }}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(W(t_{i+1})+W(t_i))(W(t_{i+1})-W(t_i))$$
$$\int_{0}^{t} W_s\circ dW_s=\frac{1}{2}\underset{n\to \infty }{\mathop{\lim }}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(W^2(t_{i+1})-W^2(t_i))\quad(\operatorname{Telescoping series })$$
$$\int_{0}^{t} W_s\circ dW_s=\frac{1}{2}\underset{n\to \infty }{\mathop{\lim }}(W^2(t_n)-W^2(t_0))$$
Therefore
$$\int_{0}^{t} W_s\circ dW_s=\frac{1}{2}(\,W^2(t)-W^2(0)\,)=\frac{1}{2}W_t^2\quad (\underset{n\to \infty }{\mathop{\lim }}W(t_n)=W(t))$$
Hence

> $$\int_{0}^{t} W_s\circ
>  dW_s=\frac{1}{2}W_t^2$$

Now use Ito lemma.

Comment: Note $\int_{0}^{t} W_s\,dW_s=\frac{1}{2}\left(W_t^2-t\right)$ whereas $\int_{0}^{t} W_s\circ dW_s=\frac{1}{2}W_t^2$ .This is the difference between Ito's  and Stratonovich's integrals